# Python : using import * at local scope

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-import, factory-pattern, template-method-pattern

I'm tring to use factory pattern (or factory method pattern) for image analysis. But memory and harddisk restriction keeps me to reduce any of dependencies as much as possible or make them as soft-dependencies. And I encountered `SyntaxError` by importing * at local scope. Sample code is below:

## Sample Project File Tree

```
.
└── root/
    ├── models/
    │   ├── pytorch.py
    │   └── opencv.py
    └── factory/
        └── __init__.py
```

## models

For this examples, `pytorch.py` and `opencv.py` have same functional unit object but the dependency is differ to each other.

### pytorch.py

```py
import torch
from torchvision.models import resnet18

__all__ = ["Resnet18Logit"]

class Resnet18Logit:
    def forward(self, img, *args, **kwargs):
        model = resnet18(pretrained=True)
        return model.forward(img)
```

### opencv.py

```py
import cv2 

__all__ = ["HOGfeatureextract"]

class HOGfeatureextract:
    def forward(self, img, *args, **kwargs):
         hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
         return hog.compute(im)

class SIFTfeatureextract:
    def forward(self, img,, *args, **kwargs):
        sift = cv2.SIFTDescriptor()
        return sift.detect_and_compute(img)
```

## factory

### **init**.py

```py
class FeatureExtractor:
    def __init__(self, lib_name, name):
        if lib_name == "pytorch":
            from models.pytorch import * # This is impossible 
        elif lib_name == "opencv":
            from models.opencv import * # This is impossible
        self.fe = eval(name)
```

`from models.pytorch import *` is the part which is the problem. The import syntax `from ~  import *` is needed to be inside of function to avoid loading all dependencies at all, but I'll produce `SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level`. I already checked '**import**' or 'importlib', but in this case both of them only imports on module level and cannot load class, which is prerequisite to make `eval()` accepts any arbitrary Class name in `__all__`.

There is any workaround or solution while keeping factory pattern and soft-dependency?

Comment: Why do you need to `eval`?! You probably simply want to work with `getattr`. `m = import_module(f'models.{lib_name}'); self.fe = getattr(m, name)`

Comment: You are right. It seems that I'm little obsessed with using eval(). Thanks!